# How to adjust the constraints for portrait and landscape view?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have 3 simple buttons, how can I adjust the constraints for portrait and landscape view like below?

**Portrait**:

[image]

**Landscape**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put these buttons under a stackview and set constraints as below

[image]

The Multipler for both height and width is set to 0.8 i.e. 80% of the dimension. And the distribution of stackview to Fill Equally. This would result in :

**Portrait**

[image]

**Landscape**

[image]

With Align center to X & Y of Superview. They will always be centered.

Comment: 1. Select stackview from left and then hold control button and draw line to Superview

Comment: 2. Reference to first Image, there is edit button when you set the multipler to 0.8 it will change the equal width to propotional width

Comment: 3. Do the same for height but this time draw the line to safe area

Comment: I think it is suitable for image view but not suitable for button inside the stackview.

Comment: Those are buttons that I've used. why do you think it's not suitable. let's discuss

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting the buttons in a view and putting height and width constraints for the button relative to the superview.

You can add constraints to the view where the views leading trailing top and bottom are relative to the superview itself or updating it as the orientation changes.